# Add local repository (Dockerfile ADD outside build context)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, podman

I am on a RHEL/CENTOS8 system that is not connected to the internet.  I have a local repo I would like to use

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
[local-rhel8-baseos]
name=Local RHEL8 BaseOS Stream
baseurl=file:///net/repository/rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
enable=1
gpgcheck=1

[local-rhel8-appstream]
name=Local RHEL8 App Stream
baseurl=file:///net/repository/rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
enable=1
gpgcheck=1

$ cat Dockerfile
'ADD /etc/yum.repos.d/ /etc/yum.repos.d/ '
'ADD /net/repository/ /net/repository/'

Error: error building at STEP "ADD /etc/yum.repos.d /etc/yum.repos.d": checking on sources under "/home/user/docker": copier: stat: "/etc/yum.repos.d": no such file or directory
```

What is the proper way to build a container using a local repository that resides outside the build context?  Note, I am building a rootless image with podman.  It is not practical for every user to create a local copy of the entire repository.  Does ADD mount the folder or try to copy it?  I would like to mount the folder similar to -v when running so the repo is available during the build

Comment: ADD tries to copy the folder, which is impossible if outside context(Dockerfile folder)
You will need to use -v when running your container, example:
`docker run -v /net/repository/:/net/repository/ your/image`
Left side of `:` in the above command is host path, right side is path inside container

Comment: Does docker build have an equiv '-v' option?  My issue is that I cannot access the folder during the BUILD process